# Difference between using PriorityQueue<T extends Priorizable> or <T extends Comparable>

Tags: java, queue, compareto

I don't know much about Priorizable. If I want to do a priority queue of integers, I would just compare each entry(compareTo()) to see where I should put the new element, but what does the "Priorizable" mean, is it an interface or what?. And what does it imply, should I implement a method or something ? is Integer a priorizable ?, please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I* don't know *anything* about `Priorizable,` which isn't part of the JDK, but unless it extends `Comparable` you can't use it with `PriorityQueue` as shown in your title. If it does extend `Comparable,` that's the only answer you need to your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Where** did you find the type Priorizable? This beast is not part of the Java API.

Have you checked the [PriorityQueue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) to see what it expects? It will tell you that it sorts objects it holds based on their natural ordering which means implements Comparable, ***or*** with a Comparator. Nowhere in the PriorityQueue API is there mention of Priorizable.

I wonder if you're talking about a custom type, an interface perhaps that extends Comparable?

Comment: Well I've seen it in many implementations, but haven't seen it in the API. So it doesn't exist ?, that means that I should use the comparable interface  for a priority queue ¿?

Comment: @FraK: `"Well I've seen it in many implementations"` -- references? Specifically, where? what implementations are you discussing? re: `"that means that I should use the comparable interface for a priority queue ¿?"` -- Yes, as per the [PriorityQueue API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html), which explicitly references Comparable type or if not, then use of a Comparator.

Comment: https://snipt.net/raw/55e2aaa7f76bf1a85eac1885c93dee46/?nice here is an implementation with Priorizable

Comment: @FraK But that isn't an example of a PriorityQueue. It's another queue implementation that extends AbstractQueue. Nothing to do with PriorityQueue whatsoever. What's your question actually about?